# How can I add a class on Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my markup :

```
  <a href="#section-one" onclick="setActive();"><div class="section-dots active-section"></div></a>
        <a href="#section-two"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
        <a href="#section-three"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
        <a href="#section-four"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

- Note, I am building my markup with the following Jquery code, dynamically:

  ```
  <script>
      var count = 1;
      var next;
      var url;
      var elementId;

      // First remove all of the dots
      $('.section-dots-container').empty();

      $('H2').each(function () {

          elementId = 'section-' + count;
          url = '#section-' + count;
          $(this).attr('id', elementId);
          $('.section-dots-container').append('<a href="' + url + '" onclick="setActive();"><DIV Class="section-dots"></DIV></a>');

          count++;
      });


  </script>
  ```

This is my script for the click event:

```
<script>
    function setActive() {
        next = $(this).find('.section-dots');
        next.addClass("active-section");
    }
</script>
```

thus it is setActive that should add "active-section" to the Div inside the anchor tag  which I am building dynamically. but I not certain if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: `'section-' + count` will return `section-1` but don't you want `section-one`? Other than that, the code looks like it should work, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would be easier to just bind the click event to your element in your js code based on its class rather than adding it into your html.

So maybe change markup to include a common class name like:

```
<a href="#section-one" class="section"><div class="section-dots active-section"></div></a>
<a href="#section-two" class="section"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
<a href="#section-three" class="section"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
<a href="#section-four" class="section"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
```

And then just bind a click event to all elements with that class:

```
$('.section').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.section-dots').addClass("active-section");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would un-capitalize the DIV and some other things in your code, but this should work if I'm understanding what you want to do.

```
$('.section-dots').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active-section');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using $(this) without passing any parameter to the function.

```
<script>
function setActive() {
    next = $(this).find('.section-dots');
    next.addClass("active-section");
}
</script>
```

useing jquery, select the element you want to add the class to it and use the `addClass("class_to_add")` function.